# Insert a character after every n characters in a text form field with flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I am trying to have a user input their birthday with the keypad. I want the format to be MM/DD/YYYY.

Once the user types in their month, I want a '/' to be appended to the text already in the TextFormField.

Can anyone share any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool backSpace = false;
int previousLength = 0;

final RegExp numRegExp = RegExp('[a-zA-Z]');
backSpace = previousLength > text.length;
previousLength = text.length;
if(!numRegExp.hasMatch(text)){
  if(text.length == 2 && !backSpace){
    String value=text.trim();
    try
    {
      int.parse(value);
      String s = controller.text.replaceRange(text.length, text.length, '/');
      controller.text = s;
      controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
    }catch(e){}
  }
  else if(text.length == 5 && !backSpace)
  {
    String value=text.trim();
    value = value.replaceAll('/', '');
    try
    {
      int.parse(value);
      String s = controller.text.replaceRange(text.length, text.length, '/');
      controller.text = s;
      controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
    }catch(e){}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was useful. You just have to use it in onchange of the textfield. Below is the code sample.

```
                    TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PopR',color: Colors.black),
                  controller: birthdayController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                  onChanged: (text){
                    bool backSpace = false;
                    int previousLength = 0;

                    final RegExp numRegExp = RegExp('[a-zA-Z]');
                    backSpace = previousLength > text.length;
                    previousLength = text.length;
                    if(!numRegExp.hasMatch(text)){
                      if(text.length == 2 && !backSpace){
                        String value=text.trim();
                        try
                        {
                          int.parse(value);
                          String s = birthdayController.text.replaceRange(text.length, text.length, '/');
                          birthdayController.text = s;
                          birthdayController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: birthdayController.text.length));
                        }catch(e){}
                      }
                      else if(text.length == 5 && !backSpace)
                      {
                        String value=text.trim();
                        value = value.replaceAll('/', '');
                        try
                        {
                          int.parse(value);
                          String s = birthdayController.text.replaceRange(text.length, text.length, '/');
                          birthdayController.text = s;
                          birthdayController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: birthdayController.text.length));
                        }catch(e){
                          
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Clr().white,
                    border: clrBorder,
                    enabledBorder: clrBorder,
                    focusedBorder: clrBorder,
                    errorBorder: clrBorder,
                    focusedErrorBorder: clrBorder,
                    errorText: (error=='n')?'':error,
                    hintText: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5.h,bottom: 2.5.h,left: 4.w),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Clr().grey,fontFamily: 'PopR'),

                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add a separator, you can do it like this.
No checks, just adds a separator.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/choice.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/map.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/rest.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/sequence.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/take_while_m_n.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  print(format(''));
  print(format('1'));
  print(format('12'));
  print(format('123'));
  print(format('1231'));
  print(format('12311'));
  print(format('123119'));
  print(format('1231199'));
  print(format('12311999'));

  print(format(''));
  print(format('1'));
  print(format('12/'));
  print(format('12/3'));
  print(format('12/31/'));
  print(format('12/31/1'));
  print(format('12/31/19'));
  print(format('12/31/199'));
  print(format('12/31/1999'));
}

String format(String s) {
  s = s.replaceAll('/', '');
  const pair = Map1(TakeWhileMN(2, 2, _any), _separate);
  const p = Choice3(
    Sequence3(pair, pair, Rest()),
    Sequence2(pair, Rest()),
    Sequence1(Rest()),
  );
  return parseString(p.parse, s).join();
}

bool _any(int c) => true;

String _separate(String s) => '$s/';
```

Output:

```
1
12/
12/3
12/31/
12/31/1
12/31/19
12/31/199
12/31/1999

1
12/
12/3
12/31/
12/31/1
12/31/19
12/31/199
12/31/1999
```

Answer (score -6):

you can own manage type then used,

```
 TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    print("First text field: $text");
  },
);
```

otherwise you can used datepicker dialog.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question.